# Read a column from excel sheet using openxlsx in R

Tags: r, excel, multiple-columns

I am trying to read a specific column using Openxls in R. The problem is that the data from the column are not together.
Following is my code:

```
library("openxlsx")
excel0111 <- loadWorkbook("C:\\path\\0111F.xlsx")
sheet_names <- names(excel0111)
c0111 <- read.xlsx(excel0111, sheet = sheet_names[1],cols = 2, rows = c(4:27)) # reading data from (B4:B27)
```

However the output looks like this:

```
    213
1   188
2   183
3   260
4   389
5   680
6  1614
7  2044
8  1544
9  1261
10 1040
11  991
12  999
13 1045
14 1133
15 1183
16 1238
17 1334
18 1122
19  690
20  607
21  524
22  366
23  390
```

I want the output as follows:

```
1   213
2   188
3   183
4   260
5   389
6   680
7  1614
8  2044
9  1544
10  1261
11 1040
12  991
13  999
14 1045
15 1133
16 1183
17 1238
18 1334
19 1122
20  690
21  607
22  524
23  366
24  390
```

Eventually, I will use a loop to get the same column  from all sheets of the excel file as follows:

```
for (i in 1:212) {


   c0111[i] <- read.xlsx(excel0111, sheet = sheet_names[i], skipEmptyRows = FALSE,cols = c(2), rows = c(4:27))
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `colNames` parameter is set to `TRUE`.  Set it to `FALSE`, and your `read.xlsx` function call won't interpret the first row as the column header:

```
c0111 <- read.xlsx(excel0111, sheet = sheet_names[1], colNames = FALSE, cols = 2, rows = c(4:27))
```